# PL/PGSQL: Store the result of a loop in a table

Tags: postgresql, loops, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I want to store the result of the following loop in a table:

```
 DO $$ 
 DECLARE rec RECORD; 
 BEGIN 
     FOR rec IN SELECT c1 FROM t1 
     LOOP 
        SELECT foo(rec.c1);  
     END LOOP; 
 END; $$ 
 LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop for that at all. In fact you don't even need a function for that:

```
insert into some_table (some_column) 
select foo(c1) 
from t1
```

Or if you want to create the table based on the query:

```
create table_some
as
select foo(c1) as some_column
from t1;
```

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name !  I am a complete novice... Sorry if my question was too basic.